# PHP How right replace text on function?

Tags: php

```
private function Photo($m,$photo){

  if($m == 'print'){
    print $photo; // or echo
  }
  else {
    return $photo;
  }
}

private function GetText(){
  ...
  ...
  $i = $res->fetch_assoc();
  $Text = $i["Text"];

    Now `$Text` have next:

     html text
     ....
     <p>%photo(2)%</p>
     <p>%photo(3)%</p>
     <p>%photo(4)%</p>
     ...
     html text

  echo $Text;
}
```

I would like replace text `%photo(N)%` (where `N` - it any number) on function `Photo($m,N)` (or function `Photo(N)`).

For this i use code:

```
$Text = preg_replace_callback("/\{photo\((\d+)\)\}/","Photo",$Text);
```

But it not work...

Tell me please how make it ?

P.S.: After replace `$Text` my example should been next:

```
html text
....
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
<p>4</p>
...
html text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Photo` is a method of the class, not a function in itself.

Try:

```
$Text = preg_replace_callback("/\{photo\((\d+)\)\}/",array($this,"Photo"),$Text);
```

For more on the `callable` typehint, check the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php).